# jquery loop animation

Tags: jquery, function, loops

i have these scrip that i need to loop:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    runIt();
})
function resets()
{
  $('.grower').removeAttr("style");
}

function runIt() 
    {
        $('.grower').animate({width: "30px",height: '30px', left: "-6", top: "-6", opacity:"0"}, 800, resets);
    }
```

but when i add the runIt(); inside it self so it can loop, it loops but my browser goes blank and i will not respond. how  can i do it so it will loop that animation.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to query the DOM constantly. Store the `$('.grower')` in a variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $grower = $('.grower');

    function runIt() {
        $grower.animate({
            width: "30px",
            height: '30px',
            left: "-6",
            top: "-6",
            opacity:"0"
        }, 800, function() {
            $grower.removeAttr("style");
            runIt();
        });
    }

    runIt();
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jC8Js/

---

**Update:** If you want it to pause before each cycle, use [a timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(runIt, 1000);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jC8Js/1/

---

Alternatively, you could just run all of it with an [interval timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $grower = $('.grower');

    setInterval(function() {
        $grower.animate({
            width: "30px",
            height: '30px',
            left: "-6",
            top: "-6",
            opacity:"0"
        }, 800, function() {
            $grower.removeAttr("style");
        });
    }, 1500);
});​
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jC8Js/2/

Comment: @YairVillar - I added some code to pause it after it loops each time.

Comment: This:

`function runIt() { ... runIt(); }`

can cause stack overflow, because there is no stop condition. It won't show up until many "iterations", but I run into an issue with a similar approach when using jquery transition() (instead on animate()) on IE9, which does not support css transitions. The sub-call was immediate, the stack run out fast. I think this recurrent approach is not exactly how this loop should be done.

Comment: @kuonirat - In that case, use `setInterval`, as shown in the 2nd example. Though once we get tail call optimization I don't think this will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/nUVbb/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    runIt();
})
function resets()
{
    $('.grower').removeAttr("style");
    runIt();
}
function runIt() 
{
    $('.grower').animate({width: "30px",height: '30px', left: "-6", top: "-6", opacity:"0"}, 800, resets);
}
```

Comment: how can i give it time after it loops each time??

Comment: add .delay(500) before .animate()