# Interval doesn't clear immediately after repeating for a while

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a bouncing arrow on my website that I created with Jquery and setInterval, like this:

```
bouncing = setInterval(function() {
    $("div").animate({
        top:"30px"
    },100,"easeInCubic",function() {
        $("div").animate({
            top:"0px"
        },100,"easeOutCubic");
    });
    console.log("bounced");
},200);
```

You can see this in place in a codepen here: http://codepen.io/mcheah/pen/wMmowr

I made it run faster than i needed because its easier to see the issues quicker. My issue is that after leaving the interval running for a few seconds, you'll notice that instead of bouncing back up or down immediately, the bouncing element will stop for half a second and then just hang there, before beginning again. If you leave it running even longer (20 seconds) and then clear the interval, you'll notice that it takes a few seconds to stop bouncing.

My questions are these:

1. Why does the bouncing go out of sync occasionally?
2. Why does the clear interval take a while to clear if it's been repeating for a while?
3. Is there a better way to have a bouncing arrow? Are CSS transitions more reliable?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: During the JS processing, the interval functions are asynchronous. So they wait until a 'break' in running code. The event gets cued then fires when there is a chance. Intervals are very inconsistent and are not recommended for events that need to run at a specific time. See: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: I honestly think it's bad UX to make stuff like this bounce/flash/glow/throb/whatever (Office 2007 had to make the "file" menu replacement button glow because it was not obvious that it was a button and it irks the $%!& out of me) but in terms of why it isn't working as desired, that's a good question (and I do not have an answer).

Comment: Don't use JavaScript for animations (well, maybe if you'll use Velocity or similar), stick to CSS animations. Also, `setInterval` is not something you would use for animation since it's asynchronous. Bottom line: keep styling to CSS ;-)

Comment: Thanks all. I'll look for a CSS workaround. @Draco18s - its for an interactive website that actually needs button elements to draw attention to themselves.

Comment: @mcheah Button elements should never need to draw attention to themselves.  The only reason would be if they didn't look like buttons.  But that's a question for [UX SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are trying to perfectly coordinate a `setInterval()` timer and two jQuery animations such that the two come out perfectly coordinated.  This is asking for trouble and the two may drift apart over time so it is considered a poor design pattern.

If, instead, you just use the completion of the second animation to restart the first and make your repeat like that, then you have perfect coordination every time.

You can see that here in another version of your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxYeyd

```
function run() {
    var self = $("div");
    if (self.data("stop")) return;
    self.animate({top:"30px"},100, "easeInCubic")
        .animate({top:"0px"}, 100, "easeOutCubic", run);
}

run();


$("div").click(function() {
    // toggle animation
    var self = $(this);
    // invert setting to start/stop
    self.data("stop", !self.data("stop"));
    run();
    console.log("toggled bouncing");
});
```

Comment: Made a few changes to avoid using a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not a good idea to mix `animate()` with timers this way. There's **NO** chance you can synchronize something like this. And there's no need to. You can simply append a function into the animation queue, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11764283/3227403
2. What `animate()` does is put an animation request into a job queue which will be processed later, when the right time comes. When you break the interval the stuff that accumulated in the queue will still be processed. There's a method to clear the queue and stop all animation immediately.
3. The JQuery animation functions actually manipulate CSS, and there is nothing beyond it in HTML. Another option would be using a canvas, but it is a completely different approach and I wouldn't recommend it. With JQuery's animation your already at the best choice.

This is a simple solution to your problem:

```
function bounce()
{
  $("div")
    .animate({
      top: "30px"
    }, 100, "easeInCubic")
    .animate({
      top: "0px"
    }, 100, "easeOutCubic", bounce); // this loops the animation
}
```

Start bouncing on page load with:

```
$(bounce);
```

Stop bouncing on click with:

```
$("div").click(function() {
  $("div").stop().clearQueue().css({ top: "0px" });
  // you want to reset the style because it can stop midway
});
```

**EDIT:** there were some inaccuracies I corrected now. The running example is on [codepen now](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrWEYX?editors=0010).

Comment: I actually wasn't able to get this working. clearQueue worked to stop the animation but I also added a console.log() to show me when the button was bouncing and the button stopped when I needed it to, but it kept on logging bounces, which messed up the timing of other animations. It may have had something to do with needing to call bounce with a  parameter to specify what element i needed to bounce, but I'm not sure. 

I used jfriend00's workaround which worked for me - thanks for your help though!

Comment: Ah, yes. That was a bug I didn't notice. I added a `stop()` before the `clearQueue()`. It works now as intended.

Comment: Just for your interest, put a `console.log()` before the `if (self.data("stop")) return;` in jfriend00's code and you'll see that it has the same problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript for animation you can use something better like the greensock tween library
http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/to/
something like this:

```
var tween = TweenMax.to($("div"), 100, {y: "100px", yoyo: true, repeat: -1});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your interval code with:

```
if(!$("div").is(":animated"))
```

This will initiate your animation only if your previous one is finished.
The reason why it was bouncing weird is that your animations are queued.
You can check how it works now:
http://codepen.io/luminaxster/pen/XKzLBg

I would recommend using the complete callback when the second animation ends instead and have variable to control a bounce recursive call in this version:

http://codepen.io/luminaxster/pen/qNVzLY